# How to find the avg number of trips per day for each month in one year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, average

I was given id, start_date, end_date in the dataset and was asking to find the average number of trips per day for each month in MySQL.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(start_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(start_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(start_date))) AS avg_trips_per_day
FROM
    trips
GROUP BY Year , Month
ORDER BY Year , Month;
```

But the returning result for avg_trips_per_day was the total number of trips in that month instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want average number of trips per day for a month, you need to ultimately divide the number of trips made in a month by the number of days in that month. At least that is my understanding of what average number of trips per day for a month mean (i.e. the number of days in the month has to factor into the calculation). If I made 3 trips on 1/1/2020 and no other trips for the rest of the year, that would be an average of `3` trips **per year**. It would also be an average of `3` trips **per month** for the month of January, 2020. But it can only be `3/31` trips **per day** for the entire month.

If you only wanted to divide by the number of days on which trips were actually made, then the question should be worded, "How do you find the average number of trips per *trip-days* for each month ..." or words to that effect.

Also, I am not sure how you want to handle a trip that begins on one day and ends on another. This SQL just looks at the start date since that is what yours is doing:

```
select year(start_date) as start_year,
       month(start_date) as start_month,
       count(*) /
       (select day(last_day(concat(start_year, '-', start_month, '-01')))) as avg
from trips
group by start_year, start_month
order by start_year, start_month
```

The expression `select day(last_day(concat(start_year, '-', start_month, '-01')))` calculates the number of days in the month given by year `start_year` and month `start_month`, which is needed because the average number of trips per day for a month is the total number of trips for the month divided by the number of days in the month.

[See Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5bc3w5Yyfm5XJCjvCiCpmH/2)

Answer (score 0):

This shows you the average trips per travelled days  for every Month and year

Spo when there where only five days this month with different startdate, it calculates the avg for every travelled day

```
SELECT     
    YEAR(start_date) AS 'Year',
    MONTH(start_date) AS 'Month',
     COUNT(*) /  COUNT(DISTINCT start_date) avg_trips_per_day
    FROM trips 
 GROUP BY YEAR(start_date),MONTH(start_date)
 ORDER BY YEAR(start_date),MONTH(start_date);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c4494f15b0709e0c1f54de1737be8ae9)

Comment: So if somebody travels 3 times on the first of of January (1/1/20) and made no other trips for the rest of that month, you would compute that his average number of trips per day for the month of January would be `3/1 = 3`. You would compute that to be higher than somebody who made three trips each and every day of January except for the last day where he made only 2 trips (`92/31). Does that really sound reasonable? I think we have a different understanding of what average number of trips per day for a month means.

Comment: The problem starts, that we don't know nothing about what days of the month we can count, for example weekend could be excluded and your calculation is wrong. I counted only days that where actually travel started, because i had nothing else to go on, and i didn't amke assumptations. And i wait if the user tells spmething more.

Comment: But I am going by my my interpretation of English, which is all I can go on. I am going to update my answer to make my point a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change one word from `YEAR` to `DAY` or `DATE`.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(start_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(start_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date))) AS avg_trips_per_day
FROM
    trips
GROUP BY Year , Month
ORDER BY Year , Month;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(start_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(start_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(start_date))) AS avg_trips_per_day
FROM
    trips
GROUP BY Year , Month
ORDER BY Year , Month;
```

> **The reason why your result was the sum of all trips per month is because the
>   result of `COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(start_date))` is 1**

So you could run both the queries below to view the difference.

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(start_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(start_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS total_trips_of_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date)) AS days_having_trips_that_month,
    COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(start_date))) AS avg_trips_per_day
FROM
    trips
GROUP BY Year , Month
ORDER BY Year , Month
```

**vs**

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(start_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(start_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS total_trips_of_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(start_date)) AS days_having_trips_that_month,
    COUNT(*) / (COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(start_date))) AS avg_trips_per_day
FROM
    trips
GROUP BY Year , Month
ORDER BY Year , Month
```